# Connect my android app to MySQL using ODBC and ASP

Tags: android, mysql, database, asp-classic, odbc

I'm trying to connect my Android app to an existing MySQL database which is currently being used in my ASP website. I couldn't find a way to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Most apps don't connect directly to remote database. Instead, they call an API (web/REST) and pass and retrieve data in JSON or XML format. This also avoids having to give out DB credential to all app users.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a Json with the data you need, from you ASP code, and read this Json on Android.